# Issues with rails_helper.rb installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I just added 'rails_helper' to my gemfile, and now when I run rake I've seeing the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `install_helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fc22a76aec8>

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@supporthud/gems/rails_helper-2.1.0/lib/rails_helper.rb:111:in `block in <class:Engine>'
```

That particular line (111) in rails_helper.rb is the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.install_helpers(Helper)
```

I've not come across issues with this before, would appreciate any pointers provided.

Thanks.

Comment: Version incompatibility?

Comment: You mean rails_helper not being compatible with the version of Rails being used?

Comment: Yes, gem may have not so strict requirements (in gem spec) but Rails had some breaking changes.